# Regarding WebService

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using webservice.Its working in website.There is a namespace in webservics i.e

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
```

I have started a project in which i am not getting namespace

```
using System.Web.Script.Services;
```

So that webservice is not working.Is there any options to get this namespace in project.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add a reference to System.Web.Extensions.

Comment: I have alredy done that.Its working in website.Problem is when implemented in project

Comment: If I understand correctly the deployed webservice is working, however, when you attempt to compile the associated project it fails due to the missing System.Web.Script.Service reference. Is this correct? If so, you want to reference the System.Web.Extensions.dll from your project.

Comment: Ben hit the nail on the head! +1

Answer (score 0):

You should add a reference at the project level, right click your project file in the solution explorer panel and select add reference.  Then browser for the appropriate library.

You can see [the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.80).aspx) on how to add/remove references in visual studio.

Comment: which dll i have to add as reference